# Show different header info based on user selection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

In my header.php file I have a "choose city" button which shows city list when clicked on. When I click on city I want contact information such as address and phone number to change according to selected city. So if a user goest to another page the updated info stays. I thought I'm gonna need to use PHP sessions, so I started with this:

JS:

```
$("#cities-list li").click(function(){
  var city = $(this).text();

  $.post("/city.php", {"city": city});
  console.log(city);
});
```

HTML:

```
   <ul id="cities-list">
     <li id="nyc">NY</li>
     <li id="la">LA</li>
   </ul>
```

PHP (city.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
    echo $_SESSION['city'];
?>
```

After I click on a city, I go and check city.php page by refreshing it, but the page is empty. Is it a wrong approach I've chosen? What is the right one? How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What does your `console.log()` output?

Comment: City.php will only return the city name if you access it from the post. It will show blank when you go to it via web browser because the only time $_POST variables are set is when you do a post action. TRY THIS: Check your network activity when you click on a link. In chrome: Inspect > Network. Then click on the link and see what the output is.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795058/how-pass-session-variable-in-javascript

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski the name of the city I click.

Comment: You could also use cookies rather than PHP session which would allow it to persist across closing the browser

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski FYI: when you post a possible duplicate and you really feel that it is, it should be "flagged" as one, not pasted as text. If others feel that it is, it will be automatically chosen to be just that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Ok thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski You're welcome :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How pass session variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795058/how-pass-session-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form submit using the `name` attribute with just html, like:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method='POST'>
  <ul id="city" name='city'>
    <li id="nyc">NY</li>
    <li id="la">LA</li>
  </ul>
  <input type='submit' id='btnGo' name='btnGo' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Then on your PHP (in this example `action_page.php`),

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
    echo $_SESSION['city'];
?>
```

Your jQuery is optional in this approach, for on page actions. Like triggering the `$('#btnGo').click()` button somewhere else on your first page.